# C# - Convert List<JToken> to List<string> one-liner

Tags: c#, json, list, type-conversion

I got a Json response from a API which contains a JArray in which there is a JProperty named "title".

I have a working one-liner which returns a `List<JToken>` which stores all the "title" properties of the Json:

```
List<JToken> queryResult = JObject
                    .Parse(client.DownloadString(url))["results"]
                    .Children()["title"]
                    .ToList();
```

I tried to edit the above one-liner so it returns a `List<string>` but without success...

Is there a way to keep it as a one-liner?

Comment: Why not deserialize it?

Comment: That "one-liner" is anything but. You put a *download* operation inside a `Parse` which means you can't check for failures or log responses that *aren't* JSON.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah you are right! Its pretty prone to crashes... Thank you for the knowledge I will change it

Comment: There's no [mcve] because you don't share you JSON, but have you tried replacing `ToList()` with [`ToObject<List<string>>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) ?

Answer (score 13):

A bit too late, but if someone requires.

```
List<string> stringList = queryResult.Values<string>().ToList();
```

may do the job.